# What does the capital $E$ notation followed by curly bracket mean?

Tags: statistics, notation

While reading through a statistics book earlier today I came across a notation I'm unfamiliar with and can't find a way to search for it. It is not expected value $E[\,]$, but instead the following. What does the '$E$' Denote here?:

> $$E\{RSS/(n-p-1)\} = \sigma^2$$
>   and that, provided $H_0$ is true,
>   $$E\{(TSS-RSS)/p\} = \sigma^2.$$

[Source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIlLp.png)

Comment: Looks like expectation. It looks like it might be trying to show that this is unbiased.

Comment: Seems equivalent to $E[\ ]$, actually one can use indifferently $E(\ )$, $E[\ ]$ and $E\{\ \}$ to denote expectations.

Comment: when the context is obvious some author even omit the bracket